# How to create dynamic layout in android

Tags: android, xml

i want to create a layout dynamically. I have tried myself but unable to get desired output.
I am new in android, Here is my XML code.

```
          <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/box_sh1">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#f4f4f4"
                android:weightSum="100">

                <Linear Layout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="75"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/yeardetail"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="April 2010 to June 2012"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:textColor="#666"
                        android:textSize="14sp"/>
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="25"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:gravity="right">
                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="25dp"
                        android:layout_height="25dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/ic_action_edit"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
```

here is a link that looks exactly i want

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create a row_layout which you want to add at runtime.. than inflate row_layout to view and than add to liniearlayout of main activity

```
 LinearLayout llGetQuote = (LinearLayout) mview.findViewById(R.id.llGetQuote);

 LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
 View row = li.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, null);
 llGetQuote.addView(row);
```

For remove a view

```
((ViewGroup) row.getParent()).removeView(row);
```

For add Clicklistner

you can set tag like

```
imgDelete.setTag(i);
imgDelete.setOnClickListener(CheckInActivity.this);
```

//onclick switch case

```
case R.id.imgDelete: 
       //here you get pos of view 
        pos = (int) v.getTag(); 

        //remove view code
break;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But i am not getting you because i think inflating a layout is not a solution.

Comment: But you can add view as many you want.. If this is not solution than will explain what you want..??

Comment: ok bro, now i am able to inflate multiple layout. But how can i assign a dynamic id to my layout, so that i can edit and delete my layout respectively..
My layout is not a list view . It is a simple activity and i am getting response on button click.

Comment: ((ViewGroup) row.getParent()).removeView(row);

Comment: sorry bro, but how can i use it on click listener. Even i don know  which item is clicked ??

Comment: you can set tag like 

imgDelete.setTag(i);

imgDelete.setOnClickListener(CheckInActivity.this);


//onclick switch case    
case R.id.imgDelete:
//here you get pos of view
                    pos = (int) v.getTag();
//remove view
              break:

Comment: are you got solution from this or not ??

Comment: yes i got a solution. Trying to upvote your answer but it says not enough reputation .

Comment: than you can accept answer so other can get help from you acceptance.

Comment: please upvote my question.I accepted your answer.